# Printing Debug statements at runtime in C per function

Tags: c, macros

I want to understand if there is a way to print debug statements for Particular method in C program.

For example:

Say I have a main function which calls other 3 functions `abc()`, `def()` and `xyz()`. Each of these methods has some print statements for debug logging purpose. If I enable the debug macro currently all the functions debug messages are getting printed, ehich creates a large log file. Say I am having some issue in function xyz() and I just want to turn on the debug statements of this function, how I can achieve this in C?

Comment: Create different macrocs for each function 
`#define DEBUG_ABC
#define DEBUG_DEF
#define DEBUG_XYZ`

Answer (score 2):

For a very simple solution, you might be able to do it with conditional compilation and naming your macros differently depending on what they will be use for (or from).

For example you could have something like (pseudo-code):

```
#ifdef ENABLE_LOG_ABC
# define LOG_ABC(...) real_logging_function(...)
#else
# define LOG_ABC(...) /* empty */
#endif
```

Then add something similar for the `def` and `xyz` functions.

To enable logging for only the `abc` function, only define `ENABLE_LOG_ABC` but no other when building. To enable for `abc` and `xyz` then define both `ENABLE_LOG_ABC` and `ENABLE_LOG_XYZ`.

With that said, if you want more advanced control and possibly by able to change such things at rtun-time, then I really recommend you try to find a third-part library which can do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

A solution without macros but requiring C coding and using an environment variable that avoids to recompile:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


void mylog(char *fc, char *msg)
{
    char *debug;

    debug = getenv("DEBUG");
    if (debug != NULL)
    {
      if (strcmp(fc, "abc") == 0 && strstr(debug, ":abc") != NULL) 
        printf("%s", msg);
      if (strcmp(fc, "def") == 0  && strstr(debug, ":def") != NULL) 
        printf("%s", msg);
      if (strcmp(fc, "xyz") == 0  && strstr(debug, ":xyz") != NULL) 
        printf("%s", msg);
    }
}

void abc()
{
    mylog("abc", "entry abc\n");
    mylog("abc", "exit abc\n");
}

void def()
{
    mylog("def", "entry def\n");
    mylog("def", "exit def\n");
}

void xyz()
{
    mylog("xyz", "entry xyz\n");
    mylog("xyz", "exit xyz\n");
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    abc();
    def();
    xyz();

    return 0;
}
```

Execution:

```
$ export  DEBUG=:xyz
$ ./debug
entry xyz
exit xyz
$ export  DEBUG=:abc:xyz
$ ./debug
entry abc
exit abc
entry xyz
exit xyz
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I like to do:

```
#define LOG_ABC 1
#define LOG_DEF 0
#define LOG_XYZ 0

void mylogger(const char *funcname, const char *fmt, ...) 
{
   if ((strcmp(funcname, "abc") == 0 && LOG_ABC) ||
       (strcmp(funcname, "def") == 0 && LOG_DEF) ||
       (strcmp(funcname, "xyz") == 0 && LOG_XYZ)) 
   {
        va_list ap;
        va_start(ap, fmt);

        vprintf(fmt, ap);
        va_end(ap);
    }
}

#define MYLOG(fmt, ...) mylogger(__FUNCTION__, fmt, __VA_ARGS__);

void abc(char *name) {
   MYLOG("Hello %s\n", name);
}

void def(int x) {
   MYLOG("Received x = %d\n", x);
}

//... and so on
```

Simply change the LOG_ABC /LOG_DEF / LOG_XYZ to enable disable logging from each function.

Infact in my own projects I use a variation of this. I also pass `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` so that the logger can also show me the file and line number of the log message - makes it easy for debugging.

More importantly, instead of using the function name, I define log categories, and log severity. So my logging looks like this:

```
MYLOG(LOG_DATAPATH, LOG_WARNING, "My log message %d %s", x, y);
```

And I can enable and disable individual categories, and also specify the minimum severity.